# Magento Change Image From Server Not Working

Tags: php, image, magento

I have a Magento website with 1k+ products, recently I've decided that I want to make a change in the pictures, resize them with a canvas behind. So I downloaded the whole media folder and tried to change an image of only one product to make a try.

Changed the size, the look and added a watermark on the picture to see if it changes. Refreshed the whole cache, deleted cache folder in the media folder and still no change with the picture in the front-end. But when I tried to access it directly it was the image I uploaded.

In the back-end I see the image I uploaded in the thumbnail of the product when editing it.

How can I fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: have a look at this thread.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19072801/change-product-image-size-on-magento-ecommerce

Comment: I don't want to resize anything inside the magento, I want to do this for each image individually, but the images just don't refresh for the new ones I upload. Only in the back end and in the thumbnail